# /pi-info/{userId} GET API in self-sign up service is not working

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to hit /pi-info/{userId} GET API by encoding the username using Base 64 encoder and given that value as userId. The response which we are getting is <!doctype html>HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Errorbody {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;} h3 {font-size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}

## HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

The username and userId values which we are using are follows:
Username: abcd@yopmail.com
Encoded value(userId): YWJjZEB5b3BtYWlsLmNvbQ==
Can you suggest what is causing this issue??

Comment: If there is any carbon error logs printed add the full stack trace here

Answer (score 0):

If you are using emails as usernames in the server append the tenant domain to username and encode that value to use as the userId in `/pi-info/{userId}` GET request

eg:

If username = abcd@yopmail.com and the user is in carbon.super tenant,

- tenant domain appended username = `abcd@yopmail.com@carbon.super`
- encoded id to be used in `/pi-info/{userId}` API =
  `YWJjZEB5b3BtYWlsLmNvbUBjYXJib24uc3VwZXI=`

NOTE:  If the username is not an email, you can use either tenant domain appended or not appended username to encode as the useId in `/pi-info/{userId}` GET request